# App crashes on button press 2.9 version of Genymotion but works on 2.8

Tags: android, button, crash, genymotion

I have two activities in my app `Alarm`, which works fine on both `Genymotion 2.8` and `Genymotion 2.9`.
I also have a `Media Player` which works fine on 2.8 but crashes on 2.9 when I press the MediaPlayer button.
This is the screen of my Alarm activity:
[image: Alarm activity]

This is the screen I get after I press the button on 2.9:
[image: Error screen].

This is the logcat after i press the button on the phone:

09-01 16:12:06.451 31541-31541/com.never.mediaalarmplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.never.mediaalarmplayer, PID: 31541
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.never.mediaalarmplayer/com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=31541, uid=10174 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=31541, uid=10174 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
                                                                            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:537)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:479)
                                                                            at com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer.getSongList(MediaPlayer.java:138)
                                                                            at com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer.onCreate(MediaPlayer.java:41)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

I had the command for requesting permission inserted in the manifest already but maybe it needs something more:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.never.mediaalarmplayer">
android:versionCode = "1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity android:name=".Alarm"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name=".MediaPlayer"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           />

        <service android:name="com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MusicService" />
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat 2.9:

```
09-02 06:34:47.269 666-677/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.never.mediaalarmplayer/.MediaPlayer} from uid 10060 on display 0
09-02 06:34:47.269 666-723/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client; transfer 4, track 48000 Hz, output 44100 Hz
09-02 06:34:47.313 1148-1167/android.process.media E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2012, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
                                                                        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:507)
09-02 06:34:47.313 2012-2012/com.never.mediaalarmplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-02 06:34:47.318 2012-2012/com.never.mediaalarmplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.never.mediaalarmplayer, PID: 2012
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.never.mediaalarmplayer/com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2012, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2012, uid=10060 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                              at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                              at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                              at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
                                                                              at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                              at com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer.getSongList(MediaPlayer.java:138)
                                                                              at com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer.onCreate(MediaPlayer.java:41)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It doesn't work on my phone either - I have Nokia 3 with Android 7.0.
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Can you add the output of `adb logcat`?

Comment: I am new so i am gonna ask I have to press the Mediaplayer button during debug mode and get the adb logcat after that right? If not please explain i am a newbie... Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that would do, but based on the logcat from your phone it looks like an issue with the version of Android instead. Were you using the same Android version with Genymotion 2.8 and 2.9?

Comment: Yes it was the 6.0 for both. I have a picture done but i cannot post more then 2 pictures yet :). I can add an logcat for 2.9 emulator also if needed.

Comment: Yes, woud be nice to have the logcat for the crash when using Genymotion 2.9.

Comment: I added the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is Runtime Permission since Android 6.0.
Adding the permission request in manifest is not enough. App should request permission in run time. If you don't want to do that, change  to 22 or less.

The reason of crash exist in Genymotion's implementation. IMHO(my guess), MediaProvider in Genymotion 2.8 does not access to external storage but 2.9 does.

Comment: Thank you for the help and sorry for the delay i was in hospital for a while. I made it work thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

According to this part of the  logcat:

`EXCEPTION: main Process: com.never.mediaalarmplayer, PID: 31541 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.never.mediaalarmplayer/com.never.mediaalarmplayer.MediaPlayer}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=31541, uid=10174 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

Your application is trying to access external storage, so you must add the matching permission to your Android Manifest file. Look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal for more details.

Comment: I already had the permission request i added my manifest also in the post maybe it needs something more added to work. Thank you for the answer :).

Comment: Thank you aswell i know you tried and you really did help me understand some things.